# После сабмита Wordpress редиректит на 404

Tags: wordpress

Сразу извинюсь за нубский вопрос, но что-то я залип.

Проблема в следующем: у меня есть форма с отправкой данных в пост, для этого подхватываю их из function.php

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['do_reviews']))
```

Тег form пустой, без action

Всё работает, всё отлично, но проблема в том, что после отработки скрипта меня редиректит на 404 страницу ( видимо, из-за того, что в юрл прописываются данные из формы ).

Как решить проблему? Если использовать header location, то не вызывается html для сообщения об успехе/неудаче.

Код из functions.php

```
add_action('wp', 'add_reviews_d');
function add_reviews_d()
{
    if (isset($_REQUEST['do_reviews'])) {
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $stars = $_REQUEST['stars'];
        $text = $_REQUEST['text'];
        $title = $_REQUEST['title'];
        $errors = array();

        if ($stars < 1 or $stars > 5) {
            $errors[] = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
  <strong>Отзыв не добавлен!</strong> Оценка должна быть 1-5.
</div>";
        }
        elseif (empty($name)) {
            $errors[] = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
  <strong>Отзыв не добавлен!</strong> Укажите имя.
</div>";
        }
        elseif (empty($title)) {
            $errors[] = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
  <strong>Отзыв не добавлен!</strong> Название должно быть заполнено.
</div>";
        } elseif (empty($text)) {
            $errors[] = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
  <strong>Отзыв не добавлен!</strong> Текст отзыва не должен быть пустым.
</div>";
        }
        if (!empty($errors)) {
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                echo $error;
            }
        } elseif (empty($errors)) {
            $post_id = wp_insert_post([
                'post_type' => 'reviews',
                'post_status' => 'draft',
                'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($title),
                'post_content' => wp_strip_all_tags($text),
                'meta_input' => ['name' => $name, 'stars' => $stars],

            ]);
            if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {
                wp_send_json_error(['message' => $post_id->get_error_message()], 401);
            } else {
                exit();
                echo "<div class='alert alert-success role='alert'>
    <strong>Спасибо!</strong> Скоро мы опубликуем ваш отзыв.
</div>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Форма:

```
<div class="collapse" id="email-form">
    <div class="card card-body">
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Оценка (1-5)" name="stars">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Название" name="title">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Текст отзыва" name="text">
            <button id="id" type="submit" name="do_reviews">Отправить</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас скорее всего метод `GET` стоит, потому и символы в URL появляются. Я так понимаю что форма у вас без аякса?

Comment: да, без него. Метод вообще никакой не указан

Comment: Для отправки данных нужно использовать `POST` подробнее [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP))

Comment: можете привести фрагмент "подхватываю их из function.php" ?

Comment: смотрите правки

Comment: @Ex1st еще приложите форму и опишите куда она должна отправиться

Comment: @Valerii Vasiliev приложил